# Working with spf record on self hosted domain

Tags: spf

I am attempting to create my spf record. Here is my scenario:

- virtual machine
- running Zimbra which is hosting domain1.com as the primary url
- has a public ip address (for example 123.123.123.123)
- several domains on zimbra (ex domain1.com domain2.com domain3.com)
- godaddy dns hosting
- my mx record points to mail.domain1.com -> 123.123.123.123
- the other two domains domain2.com and domain3.com point to mail.domain1.com for their mx record

I'd like to be able to add the 3 domains that I host to the txt record to send without problems.

This is what I have so far, but I am not sure if it is right.

This is what I have:

```
"v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:123.123.123.123 -all"
```

Do I have what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is quite what you want.  Checking your record [here](http://www.kitterman.com/recordcheck.py) resulted in a

> Warning: No MX records found for mx mechanism.

I think what you want is

```
v=spf1 +a +ip4:123.123.123.123 -all
```

which checks the originating A record is your server.  Note that this assumes that you send out all email for those domains through 123.123.123.123 rather then relaying it out through Google or your ISP for example.

Comment: that worked! tyvm!